# How can I know if the Garmin GTX 345 transponder supports modes A and C?

Tags: avionics, transponder, tcas

How can I know if the GTX 345 supports mode A/C?

I did not find a mention in the installation manual the capability of mode A/C.

Answer (score 4):

It's on the spec page: [Garmin GTX 345](https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/p/140949#specs):

> - Physical dimensions (unit, rack, connectors); for panel mounts, depth is measured from face of instrument panel): 1.65” x 6.30” x
>   10.07” (42 x 160 x 256 mm)
> - Display type: Digital
> - Weight (unit, rack, connectors): 3.1/3.2 lbs (1.41/1.45 kg)
> - Voltage range: 14/28 VDC (18/20 W Max)
> - Transmit power: 200 W minimum
> - Temperature: -40° C to +70° C
> - Operating altitude: To 55,000 ft (16,800 m)
> - Cooling input: Not required
> - Environmental compliance (TSO Approved): DO-160G
> - Software compliance (TSO Approved): DO-178 Levels B, C, D, E
> - Hardware compliance (TSO Approved): DO-254 Level C
> - TSO compliance (Approved): TSO-C88b (w/opt. alt. encoder; TSO-C112e (Class 1, Level 2els; TSO-C154c (Class A1S); TSO-C157a (Class 1);
>   TSO-C166b (Class A1S); TSO-C195a (Class C1,C2,C3,C4)
> - Mount type: Panel
> - **Transponder type: Mode A/C, S and ES**
> - Squawk code selection: Push-button
> - Traffic Information Services (TIS) alerts compatible: Yes

I have one of these units, and I can confirm that it supports A/C, S, ES, and ADS-B.

Comment: Thanks , it's possible to disable the mode s/es in this unit?

Comment: Aside from turning the transponder off, I have not seen a way to disable individual modes (at least from a pilot perspective).